# Remove n character after specific word

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

MY Data:

```
7468656.xml-87-
7468656.xml-88-
7468656.xml-89-
7468656.xml-90-
7468656.xml-91-
7468656.xml-92-
7468656.xml-93-
7468656.xml:94:
7468656.xml-115-
7468656.xml-116-
7468656.xml-117-
7468656.xml-118-
7468656.xml-119-
7468656.xml-120-
7468656.xml-121-
7468656.xml:122:
```

Desired output: Remove all(including) character after ".xml"

```
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
7468656
```

Command tried:

```
awk '{gsub(/[.xml ]/,"",$1)}9' File
```

it is only ".xml" removed from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  awk -F '[.]xml' '{print $1}' file
```

or in your way...

```
 awk '{gsub(/\.xml.*/,"",$1)}9' file
```

Comment: Quick resolution , worked , solved

Comment: Also `awk '{ sub(/[-:].*/,"") }1' file`

Comment: @Inian, that doesn't remove the `.xml` suffix. `sub(/\..*/, "")` would, but it would also break if there were other dots in the filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with below commands and it worked fine

command1:

```
awk '{gsub(/\.xml.*/,"",$0);print $0}' filename
```

command2:

```
awk -F ".xml" '{print $1}' filename
```

command3

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,6)}' filename
```

command4

```
sed "s/\.xml.*//g" filename
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    print i.split('.xml')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a scriptable editor, `ed`!

The following prints two newline-separated commands to `ed`, who we ask to silently edit the given `filename`:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/\.xml.*/.xml/' 'wq' | ed -s filename
```

1. `%s/\.xml.*/.xml/` -- on every line, search and replace the text `.xml` followed by anything with just `.xml`
2. `wq` -- write the file back to disk and quit ed

Answer (score 0):

I know it is been answered already 
but just another way of doing it using `cut`

```
cat file | cut -d "." -f 1
```

Comment: This, too, only works if the filenames in the input don't have other dots but the one in `.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`, the Swiss army knife of text processing:

```
sed 's/\.xml.*//' File
```

Comment: Note that 1), the backticks you used mean command substitution, you want single or double quotes instead, and 2) you should escape the dot, since in regexes it means "any character" (`.xml` would match e.g. `wxml`)

Comment: How embarassing! I should not post while I'm overtired! Thank you for editing!